# Can't install Chrome

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, google-chrome

I always used Chrome on my PC and today I got some problems so I decided to uninstall and re-install the software. I'm stuck now cause I can't install again Chrome. I get this result from terminal; I use these 4 commands:

```
$ wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
E: Malformed entry 4 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list (URI parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read.

$ sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
E: Malformed entry 4 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list (URI parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Malformed entry 4 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list (URI parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

See below:

[image]

**Into `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`I have 2 files of chorme**

Into `google-chorme.list`

```
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
deb <a class=vglnk href=http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ rel=nofollow><span>http</span><span>://</span><span>dl</span><span>.</span><span>google</span><span>.</span><span>com</span><span>/</span><span>linux</span><span>/</span><span>chrome</span><span>/</span><span>deb</span><span>/</span></a> stable main
deb <a class=vglnk href=http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ rel=nofollow><span>http</span><span>://</span><span>dl</span><span>.</span><span>google</span><span>.</span><span>com</span><span>/</span><span>linux</span><span>/</span><span>chrome</span><span>/</span><span>deb</span><span>/</span></a> stable main
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ xenial stable main
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ xenial stable main
```

Into `google-chrome.list.save`

```
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

Comment: Try `sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'` for the second command. 32bit versions are no more available.

Comment: @pomsky You mean this command instead of 2?

Comment: It's not working. I've just edited the question with the terminal result

Comment: You will have to remove the **google-chrome.list** file and then run this command. First run `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list` then run the command I wrote in my first comment.

Comment: Thanks I just installed it!! But when I click on the icon the window does not open...grrrrr =(

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the release code name.

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ $( lsb_release -sc ) stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
```

Comment: Using this I get the same error =(

Comment: The autogenerated-by-Chrome version is `deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main`. It has no Ubuntu release codename.

Answer (score 0):

1. `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chorme.list` has a misspelled name and lots of bogus or duplicate content; remove it. If the spelling mistake is only in your question but not in the actual file name, remove it nonetheless for the other reasons.
2. `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list.save` is supposed to be a sort of back-up of `google-chrome.list` but since I just recommended to remove the latter and am about to recommend to start from scratch, let's remove this one too.
3. Perform any of the Chrome installation procedures from the answers to “[How to install Google Chrome](/q/510056/175814)”. I specifically recommend the [answer with the 2nd most votes](/a/510079/175814); the [3rd](/a/510063/175814) does essentially the same on the command-line only.